# MongoDB Boolean naming convention

Tags: mongodb

I want to store an attribute `visible:true` in MongoDB. What is the correct naming convention for booleans `"isVisible":true` or `visible:true`

Answer (score 0):

There is no universal naming convention that covers this particular naming decision.